# Link between characters and isotypic components

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters

I am currently studying finite complex reflection groups using the book written by Lehrer and Taylor called "Unitary Reflection Groups" and I am unsure if I understood isotypic components the right way. Let $G$ be a finite complex reflection group and $I$ an irreducible $G$-module. They define the isotypic component of $I$ in regard to a $G$-module $V$ as the direct sum of all submodules of $V$ isomorphic to $I$. Later on for a $G$-module $M$ they introduce $M^G:=\{m\in M\mid gm=m \forall g\in G\}$ and describe it as the isotypic component corresponding to the trivial representation. My question about this is that $M^G$ doesn't have to be irreducible (since every element of $M^G$ is fixed by the operation of $G$ by definition every subspace of is a submodule, so it is is irreducible if and only if it is onedimensional or $0$). But because every onedimensional subspace is a submodule we can take a basis of $M^G$ and every basis vector spans an irreducible (because onedimensional) subspace. If $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is a basis for $M^G$ does that imply the isotypic component corresponding to the trivial representation is $M^G=\oplus_{i=1}^k\mathbb{C}v_i$ or did I misunderstand the definition? Because the different submodules $\mathbb{C}v_i\simeq \mathbb{C}$ are clearly isomorphic and irreducible (since they are onedimensional). So $M^G$ is not irreducible itsself, but the sum of irreducible, isomorphic submodules.

Comment: What you say about  $M^{G}$ is correct.. Likewise, if $I$ is any irreducible $G$-module ,the isotypic component of a $G$-module $V$ corresponding to $I$ is the sum (not necessarily direct) of all submodules of $V$ isomorphic to $I$. As you have noted when $I$ is trivial, the isotypic component associated to a general irreducible $I$ will be a direct sum of the form $I_{1} \oplus I_{2} \ldots \oplus I_{k}$, where each $I_{j}$ is isomorphic to $I$  and the dimension of the isotypic component is kdim(I), but not every submodule of $V$ isomorphic to $I$ need be one of the $I_{j}$ in general.

Comment: Thank you for the explanaition! This really helped me. This question can be closed (but I don't know how).